# Boost Graph Algorithm - Adding a constraint

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph

**The Problem**

I have a set of vertices that are distributed evenly (a *grid*). The distance between neighboring vertices is 1 (a normal grid unit) when going vertical or horizontal. Basically a normal grid:

[image: What the grid looks like]

Here are the constraints I have so far in my code:

- Visit every vertex
- Move *only* vertically or horizontally (not diagonal)

I just need to add one more constraint. I need to minimize the number of *turns*. That is, minimize the number of times the "salesman" will need to change directions (examples below). How would I achieve this?

**Examples**

In these two images, although all vertices are visited, the number of turns it took to get there is different. I want to minimize these turns.

[image: Path with 6 turns] [image: Path with 11 turns]

How would I achieve this?

**My Code**

I have simplified my code below (it is just a 4x4 grid for simplicity sake).

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>

using namespace boost;

int main(int, char *[])
{
    typedef adjacency_list < listS, vecS, directedS, no_property, property < edge_weight_t, int > > graph_t;
    typedef graph_traits < graph_t >::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
    typedef graph_traits < graph_t >::edge_descriptor edge_descriptor;
    typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;

    // This just creates a 4x4 vertex grid like in the examples above
    const int num_nodes = 16;
    enum nodes { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P };
    char name[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
    Edge edge_array[] =
    {
        Edge(A, B), Edge(B, C), Edge(C, D),
        Edge(A, E), Edge(B, F), Edge(C, G), Edge(D, H),
        Edge(E, F), Edge(F, G), Edge(G, H),
        Edge(E, I), Edge(F, J), Edge(G, K), Edge(K, L),
        Edge(I, J), Edge(J, K), Edge(K, L),
        Edge(I, M), Edge(J, N), Edge(K, O), Edge(L, P),
        Edge(M, N), Edge(N, O), Edge(O, P),
    };

    int weights[num_nodes];
    std::fill_n(weights, num_nodes, 1); // set all edge weights to 1

    int num_arcs = sizeof(edge_array) / sizeof(Edge);

    graph_t g(edge_array, edge_array + num_arcs, weights, num_nodes);
    property_map<graph_t, edge_weight_t>::type weightmap = get(edge_weight, g);

    std::vector<vertex_descriptor> p(num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<int> d(num_vertices(g));
    vertex_descriptor s = vertex(A, g);

    dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, s, predecessor_map(&p[0]).distance_map(&d[0]));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a penalty to the calculated cost whenever you change direction (which needs to be calculated on the fly). You can do dynamic cost calculations in bgl using:

```
boost::function_property_map<MyDynamicWeightFunctor, edge_t, float> weight_map(weight_functor);
dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, s, predecessor_map(&p[0]).distance_map(&d[0]).weight_map(weight_map));

struct MyDynamicWeightFunctor : public std::unary_function<edge_t, float> {
    MyDynamicWeightFunctor(const GRAPH_TYPE &g)
        : mGraph(g) {
    }
    float operator()(edge_t e) const {
        // You will need to do something more complicated here
        // You will need to look up where you came from. You can accomplish this
        // by passing some structure in the constructor of this functor that keeps
        // track of you previous location(s)
        return mGraph[e].weight * 2;
    }
    const GRAPH_TYPE &mGraph;
};
```

It has been a while since I've used this so have a look at how to use property maps http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html and in particular function property maps http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/property_map/doc/function_property_map.html